# RadUpload problem with firefox

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, firefox, telerik

Q:

I use **RadUpload Telerik** control
   to upload more than image ..this
   control is flexible and amazing one..
   it works perfectly but recently i
   find the following problem ::

the problem appears only in
   **firefox** not IE

when click on **Select** *button* in
   this control to select my file the
   button doesn't work at all ,,but when
   i click on the textbox(which the file
   path appear in)it opens the window
   which i can select a file from it ..
   i don't know what is the problem with
   firefox .. i wanna the default
   behavior to not confuse the user ,i
   wanna when clicking on Select button
   , showing a window to select my file
   from it like IE..

any suggestions to fix this problem
   please...

Comment: Using DevExpress, my standard procedure with issues like you describe is: Create a stand-alone example project with a proof-of-concept, then submit it to the DevExpress support forums or support area. Likely, Telerik will have something similar.

Comment: i ask if any one face the same problem before , to clarify the problem to me ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be some kind of z-index and containers overlapping issue, check the html of the page to track it. The [ajax upload demos](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/upload/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) on the telerik site does not suffer from this issue under FireFox, I checked it.